# Jdbc Adapter/Poller appears to run out of memory under heavy load

Tags: spring, spring-integration

We are testing our Spring Integration application from within Eclipse.

The application polls a DB, uses a rowMapper to create domain objects, these are then marshalled into XML(using Castor), and the XML is sent as a message downstream.
The application works well, but at some point we get heap errors.

> The VM arguments are set as follows: -Xms512M -Xmx1024M

It appears that the OutOfMemoryExceptions which are thrown occur when the poller has to handle very large result sets.

This is the configuration of the poller:

```
<task:executor id="inboundAdapterPollerPool" pool-size="1000 queue-capacity="100000" />
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="jdbcPollingChannelAdapter"
   channel="input" auto-startup="true"
   query="${sql}" row-mapper="entryRowMapper" update=""
   select-sql-parameter-source="timeRangeSqlParameterSource"
   jdbc-operations="myJdbcTemplate">
   <int:poller fixed-rate="50" task-executor="inboundAdapterPollerPool" error-channel="error" >
      <int:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManager" isolation="DEFAULT"  timeout="-1" synchronization-factory="syncFactory"/>
   </int:poller>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

The following are the two exceptions thrown during different executions:

```
INFO  org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter: started jdbcPollingChannelAdapter
INFO  org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor: Starting beans in phase -2147483648
INFO  org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor: Starting beans in phase 2147483647
ERROR org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler: org.springframework.core.task.TaskRejectedException: Executor [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1ac364e] did not accept task: org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1@1215a83
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:244)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:231)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:241)
    ... 12 more
```

and

```
INFO  org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter: started jdbcPollingChannelAdapter
INFO  org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor: Starting beans in phase -2147483648
INFO  org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor: Starting beans in phase 2147483647
ERROR org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils: TransactionSynchronization.afterCompletion threw exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.message.GenericMessage.toString(GenericMessage.java:82)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.transaction.ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor.doProcess(ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor.java:107)
    at org.springframework.integration.transaction.ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor.processAfterRollback(ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.integration.transaction.DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory$DefaultTransactionalResourceSynchronization.afterCompletion(DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory.java:93)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.invokeAfterCompletion(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:168)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.invokeAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:993)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:968)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:872)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:822)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:410)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:114)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy15.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:236)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
ERROR org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils: TransactionSynchronization.afterCompletion threw exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
ERROR org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils: TransactionSynchronization.afterCompletion threw exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Is there anything obvious wrong with the adapter or poller configuration, or what are the things I could do to overcome the memory issues

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Well, your app clearly can't keep up with the pace of polling every 50ms.

You could try setting the rejection policy to CALLER_RUNS but that will cause messages to be processed out of order (when the queue is full, the poller thread will process any new messages) but at least it will throttle the poller.

You could also write a custom `RejectedExecutionHandler` that blocks the poller thread until there's space in the queue.

That said, your queue size is rather large.

Probably the easiest fix is to reduce the poller frequency to a value that your downstream processes can keep up with.

Comment: Gary, thanks. Setting rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" , fixed-rate="200000" allows larger result sets to be handled. The issue is that on some polls the result set will be small, on others large. Setting fixed-rate to an arbitrarily high number would not be practical, as it would slow down everything for the average size result. Also, we need the system to be flexible enough to handle massive data sets we did not anticipate. 

Would a custom RejectedExecutionHandler solve that? If so, do you have any pointers/links on how to implement it and use it with Spring Integration?

Comment: Google is your friend; I just googled `taskexecutor block caller rejection policy` and a number of suggestions came up.

Answer (score 0):

seems to be the issue with your task executor configuration where you have configured the thread pool and queue with very large values '100000'.

Suggesting to tune it with some smaller values to avoid memory issues.

```
<task:executor id="inboundAdapterPollerPool" pool-size="100-500" queue-capacity="1000" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />
```

By default, the rejection policy is `AbortPolicy` which will throw the exception if queue is full. However if you need to throttle the tasks under heavy load , you can use `CallerRunsPolicy`. This allows the executor to "catch up" on the tasks it is handling and thereby frees up some capacity on the queue, in the pool, or both.

Comment: I set the queue-capacity to what we think will be the maximum number of rows read in any one SELECT by the poller, so the application will be able to handle them. Is that wrong?

Comment: in my opinion, this setting is actually leading to OutOfMemoryError. however, you can try my suggestion and @Gary's suggestion to reduce the poller frequency in combination.